# Unable to bind data to dropdown-multiselect in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please check the plunker. I'm not able to bind the data which come from server like this`(["Monday","Tuesday"])`.

I know data binds when it is like

```
$scope.selectedUser = [{ id: 2, name: 'Monday' },
                       {id: 3,name:'Tuesday'}];.
```

I want to make `["Monday","Tuesday"]` to `[{ id: 2, name: 'Monday' },{id: 3,name:'Tuesday'}]` in javascript so that it would bind in dropdown.

Please help me solve this issue.

[demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zHPeKSnMmBlKUfCX1BTJ?p=preview)

Comment: what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//This is the ng filter to create id as you get the data from server 
app.filter('createId',function(){
    return function(arr){
        var result = [];
        for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
            var id = arr[i].substring(0,3);
            var obj = {'id':id,'name':arr[i]};
            result.push(obj);
        }
        return result;
    }
});

//In js controller you can costomize your array of user by using ng-filter like this
$scope.users = $filter('createId')($scope.users);
//This is because index will be changed every time so this can't be used as ID
$scope.selectedUser = $filter('createId')($scope.selectedUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$scope.selectedUsers=[];
//serverData is data from server
for(var i =0 ; i < serverData.length ; i++){
    $scope.selectedUsers.push({id:i , name: serverData[i]})
}
```

And in your angular

```
$scope.doSelectedUser = function () {
    $scope.selectedUser = $scope.selectedUsers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.selectedUser` should have a reference to the actual objects in `$scope.users`. for example, this is what i had to change in your plunker to bind it with the users match the user names list:

```
var defaultSelectedUsers = ["Sunday","Tuesday"];

$scope.users = [
   { id: 1, name: 'Sunday' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Monday' },
   { id: 3, name: 'Tuesday' } ];

$scope.selectedUser = $scope.users.filter(function(user){
    return defaultSelectedUsers.indexOf(user.name) != -1;
});
```

**Online Demo - http://plnkr.co/edit/3TOkZEaZVSxtpNbFaNkg?p=preview**

---

You mentioned you want to do it from your server's response. it's unclear how you want to decide which one to select, assuming you rely on a default selected users by name according your example.

**This is how you handle a server's response** and modify the new selected users:

```
var defaultSelectedUsers = ["Sunday","Tuesday"];

$http.get('/api/v1/users')
    .success(function(users)){
        $scope.users = users;

        $scope.selectedUser = users.filter(function(user){
            return defaultSelectedUsers.indexOf(user.name) != -1;
        });
    });
```

You may change the filter condition to what makes sense for you

Comment: Though I got the answer from previous comment this is also very helpful & simple .. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Achieve your json using below code

```
var temp = ["Monday", "Tuesday"]
var result = "[";
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
if(i!=temp.length-1)
{
    result += "{id:'" + i + "',name:'" + temp[i] + "'},";
}
else
{
    result += "{id:'" + i + "',name:'" + temp[i] + "'}";
}
    alert(result);
}
console.log(result+"]")
```